# Does twilio task router "call" instruction accepts AMD (Answering Machine Detection) parameters?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-taskrouter

I am using twilio task router to a great effect implementing a call center functionality. When a task reservation is created, I am issuing a ["call"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#initiating-call) instruction as I need to create a call leg to the worker, something very similar to as shown in the example

```
{
  "instruction": "call",
  "to": "+15645455534",
  "from": "+15558675309",
  "url": "http://example.com/agent_answer",   
  "status_callback_url":
    "http://example.com/agent_answer_status_callback"
}
```

At this point, I would also like to [detect Answering Machine](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection). I can see providing `MachineDetection: Enable` option would result in an additional parameter `AnsweredBy` in the url callback.

But I am failing to see the support of those parameters with the [call instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#initiating-call). Is this something I can use and would work? If not, are there any other ways to achieve the goal?

**Edit:**

Tested by passing `MachineDetection: Enable` with the call instruction. The Url callback didn't receive AnsweredBy field. Checking into twilio call logs, it didn't use the parameter while starting an outbound call.

[image]

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `call` instruction itself does not support AMD. However, instead of using `call`, you can use `redirect` which will redirect the call to a new TwiML document. In that new TwiML document, you can specify the [machineDetection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-machine-detection) attribute which is part of the `<Number>` or `<Sip>` noun within the `<Dial>` verb. This feature has been supported since [October, 2022](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/answering-machine-detection-is-now-available-for-dial-and-post-to-participants-calls).